# Unable to find the webpack.config.dev.js and webpack.config.prod.js

Tags: reactjs, config

I am using npm run eject cmd to enable CSS modules.After executing the command, in the config folder i am unable to find the webpack.config.dev.js and webpack.config.prod.js . Instead i found only webpack.config.js.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the idea is that you copy the config file and then rename each copy to those names, one for dev and one for prod.

Comment: If you use the new `create-react-app` to create your project, you only get one file `webpack.config.js` for both development and production.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you get only Webpack.config.js file in the config folder. For you to enable the CSS Module, you don't need to config anything in the Webpack.config.dev.js or in the Webpack.config.prod.js. All you do is to rename your CSS file to include '.module.css' ie (rename from App.css to App.module.css) then go to your component file ie(App.js) and import the css file (ie import Style from './App.module.css'. That should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You won't find these files in the config folder.To enable CSS Module all you need to do is to include '.module.css' to your file name.